# Telnet session to ESG Signal Generator

Tags: python

I am trying to control a signal generator using python. I just need to change the amplitude and frequency.`my code is below:

```
import telnetlib
HOST = "169.145.1.1"
timeout     = 5
PORT    = 5023
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, PORT , timeout)
tn.read_until("SCPI>", timeout)
tn.write('FREQ 3ghz\r\n')
tn.read_until("SCPI>", timeout)
tn.write('AMPL 10dbm\r\n')
tn.read_until("SCPI>", timeout)
tn.close()`
```

when I open a telnet session directly on port 5023 i am able to change the Freq and Amp but not using the script above. the debug session shows the telnet connection is successful and it did send the commands but nothing changes on the sig Gen. thank you

Comment: Maybe you need to wait for the prompt after each command - perhaps it all happens too quick and you are closing the connection before it has processed the commands?

Comment: I tried waiting and it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: A bit off topic, but I have successfully used a tool called expect to do similar tasks. Might be ok to get the job done if you don't HAVE to use Python https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect

Comment: I have to use python as i am controlling other test equipment using python and i just need to add the Sig Gen. thank you

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I've tried with 2.7, and amended the answer.

Comment: i am using 2.7.12 thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out. I need to add \r\n after each command and not just \n. the Sig Gen values changed once I implemented this change. I updated the script. thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Test

I've run your code against a listening `nc`, and Python 2.7 complained that the call to `telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, PORT , timeout, Debug)` was wrong - the parameter `Debug` should have been omitted.

Actually, in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html) the Debug parameter isn't present:

> Telnet.open(host[, port[, timeout]])
>
> ```
> Connect to a host. The optional second argument is the port number, which defaults to the standard Telnet port (23). The optional
> ```
>
> timeout parameter specifies a timeout in seconds for blocking
>   operations like the connection attempt (if not specified, the global
>   default timeout setting will be used).
>
> ```
> Do not try to reopen an already connected instance.
>
> Changed in version 2.6: timeout was added.
> ```

Once fixed that, however, the commands were sent identical by telnet in raw mode and by your code. It could be some weird timing thing, but apart from that it should work.

Just to be safe I'd still run a tcpdump if I were you.

## Old answer

You aren't terminating the commands, so they are not getting executed. `.write()` [does not auto-terminate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html) commands.

```
tn.write('FREQ 1.92ghz' + "\n")
```

Also, wait for an answer before closing, just in case.

```
tn.read_until("some answer", timeout)
tn.close()
```

Comment: It's like you typed the command but didn't press return/enter. The "\n" is the return/enter.

Comment: If you send the commands and wait for an answer it *should* work. A possibility is that the telnet negotiation ruins something. Try sniffing the packets between the two machines and see whether there is any difference between a TELNET session and your code. There ought to be none, since you're likely connecting in raw terminal mode.